# Why do movies include the title of the movie in the opening credits?

Tags: title-sequence

It's safe to say 100% of the audience members know the name of the movie they're attending and don't need to be reminded in big letters on the screen.

Comment: "It's safe to say ..." - how do you get that idea? When I find an interesting movie on TV, I often wish I knew the title. The same applies to incorrectly named video files (e.g. those named automatically after recording from the TV card). Lastly, seeing the movie title in the cinema is normally the moment I start relaxing because it's my confirmation I did not accidentally enter the wrong theater.

Comment: Best Feeling ever is the moment you realize you didn't enter the wrong theater room to see snoopy. xD

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Right, but I'm not convinced lost movie goers is a big problem.

Comment: I think the downvotes are for the huge assumption that everyone always knows what they're watching, which isn't always the case

Comment: @DForck42 - That may be, but I'd be surprised if movies have been using a title card since the early 20th century as a reminder to viewers in the wrong theater. I'm guessing it's for simple artistic (or perhaps contractual) reasons but I don't know.

Comment: @RobertF movies have been around since around the early 1900's.  there are a lot of things that are still done as a tradition rather than being strictly necessary, the title sequence being one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie is also presented in Television and most of the times people don't have access to the movie name they are about to watch. So they see the name in the openning credits/title.

Also according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_credits)

> In a motion picture, television program or video game, the opening credits or opening titles are shown at the very beginning and list the most important members of the production. They are now usually shown as text superimposed on a blank screen or static pictures, or sometimes on top of action in the show. There may or may not be accompanying music. When opening credits are built into a separate sequence of their own, the correct term is title sequence (such as the familiar James Bond and Pink Panther title sequences).

So just to finish the presentation with the names of the members of the production in style, they finish with the movie title.

Movie Sequels or Prequels are also better identified by the title in the beginnining.

Also you can tell a lot how a movie is gonna be by the style and art of the openning title. Take for example Oblivion:

[image: Oblivion]

You know it's gonna be a futuristic action type movie just by the title.

BTW The openning movie titles always gives me the chills.

Comment: Movie & show titles are displayed on the menu or in your TV Guide. Plus if you're channel surfing it's likely you'll have missed the movie title anyways.

Comment: BTW *Rogue One* showed all of the credits at the end of the movie - except for the title which was displayed at the beginning.

Comment: @RobertF: At least when I'm underway, in particular abroad where I don't know channel names and [teletext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletext) isn't supplied, I often have no convenient access to a tv schedule. You're right about missing the initial title, which is why at least in my place, many TV channels typically display the show title in a small overlay also after each ad break. Which is a further sign that the premise of your question is apparently not quite true and there *is* a sufficient interest of learning what show this is in-program.

Comment: @RobertF: Skipping title sequences and only showing a title card (if at all) is a trend that (I think) started some 20 years ago ([the first X files movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120902/) and [Star Trek: Nemesis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0253754/) come to mind as earlier examples). So, *Rogue One* just followed a fashion in that respect. (Unfortunately. I really dislike that. But then, that's in part because I enjoy listening to the musical title theme for a while before the movie starts.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - *Rogue One* is a case in point. There was no opening crawl & theme music, no opening credits. What was the point of even displaying the title "Rogue One" at the beginning of the movie? It seems redundant & a distraction, doesn't it? We all know we're watching Rogue One, that's the whole reason we're sitting in the theater and paid for our tickets.

Comment: @RobertF: Please read my other comments. I have already provided numerous reasons (not to mention the very good ones presented in Gustavo's answer here), even some that apply in the comparably rare case that I watch a movie in the theater rather than elsewhere.

Comment: Sure - I didn't too many likes for this question. :-(